# Could Gothic ahs (ear of grain) and Turkish ak (white) be cogante?

Tags: turkish

Could Gothic ahs (ear of grain) and Turkish ak (white) be cogante like English wheat and white ?

Comment: Re. your edit: You can not delete your own question once it has an upvoted answer, and we won't delete it for you. For the reasons and more information, see the section "If I flag my question with a request to delete it, what will happen?" [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5222/332957).

Comment: BTW, in the future, if there is an issue that needs attention by moderators, please use the "flag" button under the post instead of editing your question -- we will not automatically notice edits unless we accidentally stumble upon the post again. I un-did your edit and restored the original question.

Comment: Repeatedly modifying the question in substantive ways is considered abuse of the site. If you continue to do so, you will trigger the automated system into taking punitive action against your account. Please do not modify the question any further.

Answer (score 2):

The Gothic   (ahs) [is derived](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Reconstruction:Proto-Germanic/ahaz#Descendants) from the Proto-European root **h₂eḱ-* 'sharp' which is not connected with whiteness in any way.

But the time and distance gap between Proto-Indo-European and Proto-Turkic is the best proof that the two words are not related in any way.

Comment: What does "distance gap" mean ? Do you know about Tocharian language ?

Comment: @Nurlan - I do know about Tocharian, it was spoken in the Tarim Basin, 2000 km away from the Turkic homeland. Do you mean the Proto-Turks borrowed the Tocharian word derived from the PIE _*h₂eḱ-_ 'sharp' which meant 'end' in Tocharian and started using it to mean 'white'?